# How to do a forward in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Is there some way to do a forward in Codeigniter? I need to call another method of my controller in the same requisition, but the redirect will do another requisition.

Comment: Do you mean calling a controller with in a controller? Is o cannot do that with normal codeigniter you need third party called HMVC

Comment: There is a redirect method in codeigniter: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect